# How to change button text on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this slideToggle code. When I click the button that says "open", it changes the text to "close". It stays as "close"d even if you click it again so I want to change the text back to "open" when I click on "close" and vice versa.

```
  <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        $('#flip').html("close");
        reset ();
    });
});
</script>

<style> 
#panel,#flip
{
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
    padding:50px;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="flip">open</div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        var t=$('#flip').html()==='close'?'open':'close';
        $('#flip').html(t);
        reset ();
    });
});
```

Better you can have a boolean to check what you are showing. like:

```
var showingClose=false;

$(document).ready(function(){
......
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    if(showingClose){
        $('#flip').html('open');
    }else{
        $('#flip').html('close');
    }
    showingClose = !showingClose;
.......
```

As pointed out by [@filoxo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554793/filoxo) in comment, better to use `$('#flip').text()` to get/set value.

Comment: While this works for the current case, this could break easily and cause issues if another html element is placed inside the div with id="flip". Something like `<div><p>Open</p></div>`. This is because the `.html()` method will return the *entire* inner html value, tags and all. Just a consideration!

Comment: @filoxo sure, but as it is being set from here only there is lesser changes. Moreover seems he is just experimenting. This does not look like production code.

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle the css class. Check http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").toggleClass("flip");
    });
});
```

css:

```
#panel
{
    padding:50px;
    display:none;
}
.flip
{
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage jQuery's [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) function in conjunction with the [visibility selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to determine if the element is displayed or not. This is better than a boolean in my opinion and is also better for readability. Lastly, using a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx) can help you set the button text correctly based on said visibility.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        var btnTxt = $("#panel").is(":visible") ? "close" : "open";
        $('#flip').text( btnTxt );
        reset ();
    });
});
```